# Why passing multiple values with | work as arguments to a function on Golang?

Tags: go

I was looking at the os package docs and saw this:

```golang
f, err := os.OpenFile("access.log", os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY, 0644)
```

According to the docs the `OpenFile` signature its

```golang
func OpenFile(name string, flag int, perm FileMode) (*File, error)
```

Why does this works passing `os.O_APPEND|os.O_CREATE|os.O_WRONLY` as the second argument?

Comment: Because you or multiple flag constants into a single flag integer. Think about them in binary, check their binary values and what or-ing them returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constants `os.O_APPEND`, `os.O_CREATE`, and `os.O_WRONLY` are `int`s, so  this is taking the bitwise OR operation on them and combining them into a single `int`.